# Question about manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sign}$$
Given the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with
$f(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{-x y} (\sgn(y)-\sgn(x)) (1 - \sin(\frac{π}{4}+4 \tan^{-1}(y, x)))}{2 \sqrt{2}}$.

Which [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKjLU.gif). Is this a manifold? My problem in understanding is this: This does not look like it is differentiable at the origin. However in dimensions 1-3 every manifold should have a smooth structure. So now I am confused if this even is a topological manifold.

Comment: Ate you asking if the graph of f is a manifold?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes

Comment: The map $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ may be an embedding of $\Bbb R^2$ in $\Bbb R^3$ *as topological manifolds* **and** $\Bbb R^2$ has a smooth manifold structure in its own right which is compatible with the aforementioned structure of topological manifold, **but** this doesn't mean that  $f$ is an embedding of $\Bbb R^2$ in $\Bbb R^3$ *as smooth manifolds*.